# Tab-delimited Hive table: Tabs are being removed

Tags: excel, macos, hadoop, hive

I've started using hive at work and I've run into a problem with woo tab-delimited databases I am pulling data from. Upon importing the data into Excel (for Mac), I noticed that some columns merged when they should be separate.

I've run the query without certain columns and it seems that it has to do with cells with long data. Sometimes the numbers will be gobbled by the letters of the other cell.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: Needs sample data

Comment: The output looks something like:  
  
123456   The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 12.345.67  
  
it should be something like:  
123456   The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 12.34 5.67

I'm retrieving data from 5 columns.

Comment: From where exactly do you run the query (hive cli / beeline / Excel)?

Comment: I run it in Hive CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the following method

```
insert overwrite local directory '/...path.../my_directory'
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '\t' 
stored as textfile
select * from my_table
;
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries